# Detect div where clone was dragged.

Tags: jquery

Hi I have this code and I am trying to detect which div each clone goes.

```
$(function() {      
        $('#draggableImages img').draggable( {
            helper: "clone",
            containment: '#dropbox',
            cursor: 'move',
            revert: 'invalid'
        })

    $("#Sunday").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable[0].id) {
            $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());
        }
    }

});

.
.
.

    $("#Saturday").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable[0].id) {
            $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());
        }
    }

});
```

My div checking does not work here's how i tried. This is the part I  believe where the clone should be detected when the button is clicked

```
$( '#Checkdiv input[type=button]' ).click(function(){
    if($("#Monday:has(camera)").length > 0){
        alert("Camera");
    }
    else if($("#Monday:has(star)").length > 0){
        alert("star");
    }   
    else{
        alert("no");
    }
});


    });
```

Comment: Do you mean to detect x, y position from where element was initially dragged?

Comment: i wanted to know if the divs from sunday to saturday has a star/camera in them.

Comment: but my problem is when i drag the clones to each div, it seems they do not become an element of that div

Comment: You would definitely check within the `drop: function(){`. Simply use a web inspector to check the dom, then use standard traversal methods.

Comment: you have an element with name camera <camera></camera>?, I ask because `:has(camera)`

Comment: maybe you want `.camera`

Comment: yes the two images are `<img id="camera" src="Assets/1_48x48.png"/>
    <img id="star" src="Assets/Star.png"/>` they belong to div draggableItems

Comment: ok, you want `:has(#star)` or `:has(#camera)`, but I don't know if that solves your problem, it should as far as I see.

Comment: When I used this `helper: "clone",` did the clone also carried the image's id when it was dropped?